# Generating UML Class Diagram

Tags: java, class, uml, diagram

Is there any specific tool to generate UML class diagram for the whole java project.
i tried with ObjectAid UML plugin and generated a UML class diagram. I need to generate class diagram for all the classes by selecting the project src folder. Is there anyway to generate it?

Thanks.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Or are you looking for a stand-alone application?

Comment: am using Eclipse 3.3.1 .

Comment: Try asking at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

I'm biased but you should also check out the [Code Understanding Tool](http://atxa.io/QdM5ie) from Architexa.  It will generate a layered diagram for you of your whole code base.  You can create class diagrams for individual packages or classes.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Eclipse or its plug-ins, but you can surely do it in Netbeans. [Here is how](http://blogs.oracle.com/JavaFundamentals/entry/generating_uml_from_the_netbeans).

Official page of [Netbeans UML Plugin](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetbeansUML).

Answer (score 1):

The best reverse engineering that I have ever seen is EclipseUML Omondo.

You can use the Eclipse 3.3 and test during 30 days the EclipseUML build: 
See dowload page at: http://www.ejb3.org/download_studio_eclipse_3.3.html
This is Plenty of time enough to create class and sequence diagrams from existing code.

Answer (score 0):

See this article: http://java.dzone.com/articles/reverse-engineer-source-code-u

I think it describes exactly what you need.

Comment: yeah thanks.. it seems to be good.

Comment: thank u Alex. this approach seems to great. itz very helpful .

Comment: compare too EssModel UmlGraph seems to be good.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [MoDisco](http://www.eclipse.org/MoDisco/) Eclipse plugin

Comment: thank you guys.. i generated  class diagram using EssModel2.2 . looks great .

Answer (score 0):

You can try Sparx EA tool:   http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/

But if there is too many classses in a  package you may get very "ugly" class diagram

Answer (score 0):

You can use UMLgraph: http://www.umlgraph.org/

It creates output for graphviz, which will layout the different clases.
It is written as a plugin (doclet) for javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try tags2uml, which takes in a tags file produced by ctags, and produces a DOT file which can be transformed by GraphViz into a UML class diagram: https://github.com/ruben2020/tags2uml